# Configuring dump directory with Maven AspectJ plugin

Tags: maven-3, aspectj

We have just now started using the AspectJ Maven plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/index.html) with our multi-module Maven based project.  This plugin generates core dump files in our project's root directory.  The AspectJ documentation claims that the system property

```
org.aspectj.dump.directory
```

can be used to configure the location where these core files are generated.

Does anyone know how to set this property (or equivalent) when using the Maven plugin?